# making a box in beamer -- center aligning the title

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I want to center align the word prediction in the following.  I would appreciate any help in doing so.

```
\documentclass[professionalfont, fleqn]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,positioning,fit,shapes.misc}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\centering
 \only<1>{%
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
 box/.style = {draw,rectangle,minimum size=1.0cm,text
width=1cm,align=center}
 ]
\matrix (conmat) [row sep=0cm,column sep=0cm,ampersand
replacement=\&] {
\node (tpos) [box,label=left:\( \mathbf{p'} \),label=above:\(
\mathbf{p} \),] {};
  \& \node (fneg) [box,label=above:\textbf{n},] {$\checkmark$}; \\
 \node (fpos) [box,label=left:\( \mathbf{n'} \),] {$\checkmark$};
  \& \node (tneg) [box] {$\checkmark$}; \\
  };

\node [left=.05cm of conmat,text width=1.5cm,align=center]
{\textbf{actual \\ value}};
\node [above=.05cm of conmat] {\textbf{prediction}};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Word prediction is centered with your matrix because it includes label's row and column.

(Added by Andrew Stacey: see picture below, the extra square is the "bounding box" of the matrix and the coordinate `(conmat)` is at the centre of this box)

[image: box around matrix]

If you want to align center of `prediction` with the central line of your matrix you can use something like

```
\node [above=.05cm of conmat.north-|tpos.east] {\textbf{prediction}};
```

`conmat.north|-tpos.east` represents the point interesction of a horizontal line crossing `tpos.south` and a vertical one corssing `conmat.north`.

In a similar way you can align `actual value` with your matrix horizontal division line:

```
\node [left=.05cm of conmat.west|-tpos.south,text width=1.5cm,align=center]{\textbf{actual \\ value}};
```

[image]

Comment: I'd just gotten as far as compiling the picture showing how big the matrix node is, rather than waste it I thought it worth while adding to your answer - hope you don't mind.

Comment: @AndrewStacey: of course! editions like this one are always welcome!

Answer (score 3):

I think a little structure would be beneficial if you are going to make more complicated ones similar to this...

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,matrix}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\centering
\only<1>{%
 \begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (conmat) [
draw,
matrix of math nodes, 
nodes in empty cells,
ampersand replacement=\&,
nodes={minimum size=1cm,outer sep=0,inner sep=0,anchor=center}
] {
                     \& \checkmark \\
\checkmark           \& \checkmark \\
  };
\draw (conmat.north) -- (conmat.south) (conmat.east) -- (conmat.west);
\node[above=2mm of conmat-1-1] {\(\mathbf{p}\)};
\node[left =2mm of conmat-1-1] {\(\mathbf{p'}\)}; 
\node[left =2mm of conmat-2-1] {\(\mathbf{p'}\)};
\node[above=2mm of conmat-1-2] {\textbf{n}};

\node [left= 4mm of conmat,text width=1.5cm,align=center] {\textbf{actual \\ value}};
\node [above=4mm of conmat] {\textbf{prediction}};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]